# Ubuntu 22.10 freezes in power management settings

Tags: power-management, freeze, battery, 22.10

I use Ubuntu 22.10 in dualboot with Windows 11 that came pre-installed with the laptop.

Laptop specs:
MSI GF 76 Katana
I5-12450h
GeForce 3050

Problem:

When I open power management settings, the system freezes after 5+ seconds being there. It does not matter if I change any settings or just has the window opened.

Everything just stops working. Laptop's fans go really loud, though. If youtube video is playing it the background, I can still hear audio from it. Problem exists in both wayland and xorg.

I use alt+prtscr REISUB to restart the system.

I guess the problem can be related to the MSI software in Windows 11 that blocks battery charging over 60% to "protect" it. It works in Ubuntu too if turned on in Windows 11. I don't really know if it actually protects the battery and increases its life time, but I prefer to trust it.

Is there a way to fix that problem without turning MSI options for battery off?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem now occurs in any type of settings, not only power-related.